# basic logic question involving arithmetic

Tags: word-problem

The territory of a polar bear is 10 square miles and there live 1000 pengunies in each square miles. Penguins can run 7 mil/hour on land and swim 20 mil/hour and polar bear runs 25 mil/hour and swims 10 mil/hour.7% of the territory is near a sea and the bear can only eat one penguin each hour.How many penguins can the bear eat in one month? My rationale is that since ((1000*10)*(1-7%)) penguins live on the land and penguins are short in speed on the land, but faster in the sea, the bear can only eat (24*30) penguins each month given that it can only eat one penguin in each hour.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What's a polar bear doing in the high southern latitudes?

Comment: I have no idea how the polar bear got there he he .